# Check Disks Powershell

Tags: powershell, diskspace

I am creating a powershell program that is supposed to check the free Disk Space of all the drives on a computer. I have found

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk |Format-Table DeviceID, freeSpace, Size
```

which generates the data I want in a table.

However I am not sure how to use each specific element in formulas and other parts of the program.

Ultimately I want to check every disk on the computer to see if its more than 50% free, and emit an output accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use the `Format-*` cmdlets *before* the point at which you need to acutally format and present the data to a user.

To grab the properties of an object without formatting it, use `Select-Object`:

```
$DiskInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk |Select-Object DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size
```

To get the percentage of free space, you could use [a calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$DiskInfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk |Select-Object DeviceID,@{L="FreeSpacePercentage";E={100*($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size)}},FreeSpace,Size
```

Since `Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk` returns an object *per disk*, `$DiskInfo` is now an array of objects with the exact 4 properties you selected.

Iterate over the array with a loop or the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and output accordingly:

```
$DiskInfo |ForEach-Object {
    if($_.FreeSpacePercentage -gt 50){
        Write-Host "There's more than 50% free disk space on drive $($_.DeviceID)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks good, except the write-host line just displays "There's more than 50% free disk space on drive" and doesn't specify which Drive

Comment: That's just because my fat fingers can't spell **DeviceID**, fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -computername $env:computername |

Select-Object DriveType, @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.Capacity/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpacePerCent";Expression={"{0:N0}" -f(100*$_.freespace/$_.capacity)}} | 
Where-Object -FilterScript {[decimal]$_.FreeSpacePerCent -gt 50 -and $_.drivetype -eq 3} |
Sort-Object -property "FreeSpacePerCent" 
Format-Table
```